# in mssql get first, second, third weekdate of current month, what date would it be the next month

Tags: sql-server-2016, weekday

Given a date lets say Aug 2, 2019 which is first friday of the month. what would be the first friday of next month (sept 6th). Now lets say I have sept 26th which is the last thur of the month. what date would it be for the last thur of next month. I have to do this in MSSQL.

Comment: "*I have to do this in MSSQL."* Great! Good luck and please do share the answer when you have it. If you get stuck, please do edit this to ask a question, and show your attempts, along with describing why what you have doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What would you do for the option of September 12th? Sounds like you have two separate scenarios.

In either case, I would use a Date Table or Calendar Table if you have one. If not, set one up. I highly recommend it. Ed Pollock does a great article on what a date table setup would look like here: [Designing a Calendar Table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/). SQLServer.Info has a good example of the table here: [Table Example](http://www.sqlserver.info/database-design/how-to-create-a-date-table/). Second example for good measure [Table Setup](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

[Table Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scJeP.png). This is how it should look. Or at least something similar. You can add more columns to do more comparisons.

Once you have your calendar table set up, its a matter of comparing the date you want to the table.

This is how you can grab the first week of the next month based on a date table

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '8/2/2019';

SELECT       [dt].Date
       FROM  [Datetbl] AS [dt]
       WHERE [dt].[Weekday] = DATEPART([weekday], DATEADD(day, -1, @Date)) -- is same day of the week
             AND [dt].Month = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)) -- Grab the month number for "Next Month"
             AND [dt].Year = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)) -- Grab year of next month since that will be different for December
             AND [dt].[WeekOfMonth] IN
     (SELECT       MIN([WeekOfMonth])
             FROM  [Datetbl] AS [dt1]
             WHERE [dt1].[Weekday] = DATEPART([weekday], DATEADD(day, -1, @Date))
                   AND [dt1].Month = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date))
                   AND [dt1].Year = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date))
     ); -- returns Sept 6
```

This is how you would go about getting the last weekday of the month based on a date table

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '9/26/2019';

SELECT       [dt].Date
       FROM  [Datetbl] AS [dt]
       WHERE [dt].[Weekday] = DATEPART([weekday], DATEADD(day, -1, @Date)) -- is same day of the week
             AND [dt].Month = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)) -- Grab the month number for "Next Month"
             AND [dt].Year = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)) -- Grab year of next month since that will be different for December
             AND [dt].[WeekOfMonth] IN
     (SELECT       MAX([WeekOfMonth])
             FROM  [Datetbl] AS [dt1]
             WHERE [dt1].[Weekday] = DATEPART([weekday], DATEADD(day, -1, @Date))
                   AND [dt1].Month = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date))
                   AND [dt1].Year = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date))
     ); -- returns Oct 31st
```

Hope this helps.